# Arrow key keypress events not firing when two other keys are being held down

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode!==37 && e.keyCode!==39) alert(e.keyCode);
});
```

When I hold down the left and right arrow keys the up arrow doesn't fire an event when I press it, why is this? and is there a way around?
I noticed a couple other combinations that do this as well,
I tried it in Microsoft Edge and Chrome 45

https://jsfiddle.net/qrjtwoa2/3/

Comment: you're keyboard must have 2kro (no, I'm kidding)

Comment: Actually, it does work for me, in chrome 44. What's your keyboard model? Maybe it really does have 2kro (it can only register 2 keys at a time/2 key rollover)

Comment: Dell SK-8115, it works with the down key though, although I wouldn't be surprised if its my keyboard, it's not a very good one, about 7 or 8 years old

Comment: it seems that keyboard has more than 2kro, but you might want to test that you can press side arrows and up at the same time in another program just to make sure

Comment: I tried it with another keyboard and tried it on my desktop, same thing.

Comment: interesting. Well, for me, it works as expected, in chrome beta 44, I hold down both side keys, then I press up key and alert appears

Comment: I see the same issue, and I can't narrow it down. I'm seeing this in my Linux keyboard config app, Firefox 35, and Chrome 42.

Comment: Possible reason: https://superuser.com/questions/420737/up-arrow-left-arrow-spacebar-is-not-working

Comment: Interesting.  I get the same behavior on my HP Pavilion laptop keyboard.  Left + Right held down, and pressing Up I do not see an alert.